# Cost functions equation manipulation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In his classic article (Nerlov, 1963), Nerlove derives the following cost function for electricity generation:
\begin{equation}
\ (1) \ \ \ C = \beta_1Y^{\beta_2}P_1^{\gamma_1}P_2^{\gamma_2}P_3^{\gamma_3}v
\end{equation}

Where C is total production cost, Y is output (Measured in kilowatt hours), P1 is the price of labour input, P2 is the price of capital input, P3 is the price of fuel, and v is the disturbance term Theoretically , the sum of price elasticities should be 1:
\begin{equation}
\ \gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3 = 1
\end{equation}

and hence the cost function may be rewritten:

\begin{equation}\ (2) \ \ \ 
\frac{C}{P_3} = \beta_1Y^{\beta_2}\biggl(\frac{P_1}{P_3}\biggl)^{\gamma_1}\biggl(\frac{P_2}{P_3}\biggl)^{\gamma_2}v
\end{equation}

He however handwaves how he obtained this result.

Now I understand what should be the first step.

1.

\begin{equation}\  \ \ \ 
\frac{C}{P_3} = \beta_1Y^{\beta_2}P_1^{\gamma_1}P_2^{\gamma_2}P_3^{\gamma_3-1}v
\end{equation}

However I have get lost on how to continue. I would appreciate any tips or tricks.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$  \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \gamma_3 = 1  \text{,}  $$
we have
$$  \gamma_3 - 1 = - \gamma_1 - \gamma_2  \text{.}  $$

So $P_3^{\gamma_3 - 1} = P_3^{-\gamma_1} P_3^{-\gamma_2}$, giving the two denominators you are trying to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
C &= \beta_1Y^{\beta_2}P_1^{\gamma_1}P_2^{\gamma_2}P_3^{\gamma_3}v\\
\frac{C}{P_3} &= \beta_1Y^{\beta_2}P_1^{\gamma_1}P_2^{\gamma_2}P_3^{\gamma_3-1}v\\
&= \beta_1Y^{\beta_2}P_1^{\gamma_1}P_2^{\gamma_2}P_3^{\gamma_3-(\gamma_1 + \gamma_2+\gamma_3)}v\\
&= \beta_1Y^{\beta_2}P_1^{\gamma_1}P_2^{\gamma_2}P_3^{-\gamma_1-\gamma_2}v\\
&= \frac{\beta_1Y^{\beta_2}P_1^{\gamma_1}P_2^{\gamma_2}v}{P_3^{\gamma_1+\gamma_2}}\\
&= \beta_1Y^{\beta_2}\left(\frac{P_1}{P_3}\right)^{\gamma_1}\left(\frac{P_2}{P_3}\right)^{\gamma_2}P_3^{-\gamma_2-\gamma_1}v
\end{align*}